# How can I store data DataFrame names to call DataFrames later?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a code to create multiple subset DataFrames from the given DataFrame. Where the name of subset DataFrame is column names of initial DataFrame.
DF is an initially given big DataFrame.

```
column_names=DF.columns.to_list()

for i in range(1,len(DF.shape[1])):
    start=a
    end=b
    globals()[column_names[i]]=DF.iloc[a:b,[0,i]]
```

This `globals()[column_names[i]]` creates dataframes with the names which are column names from the initial DataFrame DF.

I want to store created subset DataFrame names to call these DataFrames later.
for ex.

if `column_names=[A,B,C]` and created new dataframes are `A,  B and C` I want to store the names of dataframes, so when I recall `A` it will give as output the DataFrame A.

sample for DF:

| Time | Well_1 | Well_2 | Well_3 | Well4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-02-2015 | 1100 | 1500 | 900 | 8000 |
| 01-02-2016 | 1000 | 1600 | 700 | 7000 |
| 01-02-2016 | 900 | 1400 | 500 | 5000 |

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the original df?

Comment: Use a dictionary where the key is the name and the value is the df

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I provided a sample for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know how to use `globals` in this name but one approach to solve your problem would be to assign a name (column name) to all dataframes you create. Here I assume the every subset contains the column `Time` and one of the columns. It works the same way any way you filter, so this is an example:
So, first create the subsets and append them to a list, and create a list of names (the column names)

```
column_names=DF.columns.to_list()
sets = []
names = []
for i in range(1,DF.shape[1]):
    A = pd.DataFrame(DF[['Time',column_names[i]]])
    B = column_names[i]
    sets.append(A)
    names.append(B)
```

Then use `zip` to assign each df  its name:

```
d = dict(zip(names,sets))
d
```

which gives:

```
{'Well_1':          Time  Well_1
 0  01-02-2015    1100
 1  01-02-2016    1000
 2  01-02-2016     900,
 'Well_2':          Time  Well_2
 0  01-02-2015    1500
 1  01-02-2016    1600
 2  01-02-2016    1400,
 'Well_3':          Time  Well_3
 0  01-02-2015     900
 1  01-02-2016     700
 2  01-02-2016     500,
 'Well4':          Time  Well4
 0  01-02-2015   8000
 1  01-02-2016   7000
 2  01-02-2016   5000}
```

so, for instances:

```
d['Well_1']
```

is the dataframe

```
   Time  Well_1
0  01-02-2015    1100
1  01-02-2016    1000
2  01-02-2016     900
```

Comment: thank you; it worked pretty well!

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forgot to accept the answer to take it away from the unanswered questions. HAPPY CODING!